# Tangential velocity after ball strikes wall

Tags: kinematics, rotational-dynamics

I have to solve a problem where there is a ball that goes in the perpendicular direction towards a wall. It strikes the wall and goes back at the same angle it came from. (All the movement are horizontally ). Before the strike ball had a tangential velocity. My question is,  if the strike was perfectly elastic, can I assume that on the beginning  of the ball's movement after strike ,it's tangential velocity is zero?? 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Perhaps an image could be helpful. At the moment I have a problem seeing how the ball can move *perpendicular towards the wall* while having a *tangential velocity*

Answer (score 0):

If the collision is perfectly elastic, and if the ball is perfectly round, and if the wall is perfectly smooth and level, then the angle of incidence of the ball will equal the angle of reflection. So if the ball strikes the wall head on, ie with no component of velocity along the wall, it will reflect with no component of velocity along the wall immediately after impact.